# How to redefine a CSS class for the whole document?

Tags: css

So I've got style.css which defines all my CSS classes. But I want to redefine a class for an entire page without modifying style.css. I know I could override the CSS properties by using the style attribute on each element, but I don't want to do that.

So let's say I've got the class colortext defined in style.css with color:blue; but I want it to be color:red; for one entire page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What you're referring to is actually called an inline style *attribute*. The style tag (or style element) is `<style>`, which you can use to define a rule for your class within that page's `<head>` and it will apply to all your elements in that page with that class.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, yes, you're right. I knew that, just was typing too fast :P

Comment: Wow, I'm appalled by how many of these answers suggest using `!important`.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with `class` and `id` , please read http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/ . You can use an inline style, or include style2.css for that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always place a

```
<style type="text/css">
    .colortext { color: red; }
</style>
```

in your HTML document somewhere inside the `<head>` tag... however I'd recommend simply adding a rule to your stylesheet, if possible.

Comment: Yesss, perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I realize I could have added a new rule, but it's really a one time thing so it didn't seem worthwhile to add any extra code to my main css stylesheet.

Comment: You should put this in `<head>` instead of `<body>` to make it valid (at least while HTML5 scoped styles aren't yet supported)...

Answer (score 1):

Now define your `body id` and do this `css` as like this

```
<body id="home">
<p class="red">hello</p>
</body>
```

**Css**

```
#home .red{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add `style` tag top of your head closing tag and create same class add each element with `!important`

```
   .old_class{
        color: new_value !important;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you would need !important in this case. I'm far from a CSS expert, but I believe the order of operations when it comes to overrides is: within the element itself > within the document > in the stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

Override is an option

```
* { color:red !important; }
```

This isn't a good way, ( but, I thought it sounded like he was implying he didn't wan't to use `id`s or `class`s )